# Bake texture to another object

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Not sure if this is possible, but I got a one object `A`, that is nice textured.
Another object had to be made, but it's a slightly different mesh, not that much though. (a few more edges, and vertices different bones, etc...) overall they look quite the same though. I cannot make the UV unwrap the same for object `B`.

And now, I wonder is it possible to bake the texture from A upon the modified object `B`, where `B` who would use the most nearby color of object `A`?

Comment: Yes it's possible, bake Diffuse baking pass and uncheck Direct and Indirect n bake settings, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102831/game-asset-texturing-high-poly-to-low-poly

Comment: Thanks for pointing that link

Answer (score 1):

Select both objects (untextured last), in Render Options under "Bake" set Bake Mode to "Textures" and activate "selected to active"

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/1egnqp/how_do_you_transfer_textures_from_one_mesh_to/