# How to bake two objects (an item and a shrink-wrapped decal on it) into one texture image?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I'm very very new to blender and have been searching on how to do this for a while now to no avail, please forgive me if I'm posting a simple/answered question.

I am making a very simple mask that consists of 2 parts:

1. The mask itself - A rounded shape with a flat color image + some noise for texture as the material:
   [image]
2. A "decal/sticker" - an image as a plane, with a subdivision and shrinkwrap modifiers, parented to the mask.
   [image]

I would like to bake these two together, as they appear now, into 1 texture image that I can simply apply to the mask itself.  I've been able to bake them individually, but I do not know how to combine the two into 1 texture. How do I do this?

Comment: My biggest hurdle is just that I don't know how to make a UV map/texture that combines both their unique textures together.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164277/add-two-principled-bsdf-with-aplha/164279#164279

Comment: is there a reason that the decal is done with a shrinkwrap thats forbids combining the materials as josh sanfelici points out? Here is something related to general texture baking from one object to another: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102831/game-asset-texturing-high-poly-to-low-poly

Answer (score 0):

1:UV Unwrap the sphere
2. Plug the image of the decal directly into the output of the material node.
3: Select the sphere so its active(Yellow) and drag to select the decal so it is selected(Orange)
4. In the shader editor, create an image with a resolution of say 1024x1024 or 2048x2048.
5. In the bake settings in the render properties panel, switch the bake type to emission, Check selected to Active.
6.Click Bake.

Also, you can apply this detail in texture painting by adding it as a mask in the brush settings.